# Python 3, need help looping something

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

I'm trying to learn Python 3 and I'm wondering how I would loop something...

```
print("how many cats do you have?")
numCats = input()
try:
    if int(numCats) >= 4:
        print('That is a lot of cats.')
    elif int(numCats) in range(1, 3):
        print('That is not that many cats.')
    elif int(numCats) == 0:
        print("Oh, you have no cats.")
except ValueError:
    print('You did not enter a number.')
```

I want to make it so that when it says, "You did not enter a number." it loops back to "How many cats do you have?"

Comment: have you looked up 'python loops'?

Comment: Why don't you want to print anything if there are 3 cats?

Answer (score 1):

```
while True:
    print("how many cats do you have?")
    numCats = input()
    try:
        if int(numCats) >= 4:
            print('That is a lot of cats.')
        elif int(numCats) in range(1, 3):
            print('That is not that many cats.')
        elif int(numCats) == 0:
            print("Oh, you have no cats.")
        break
    except ValueError:
        print('You did not enter a number.\n')
```

This keeps looping forever (Because of the `while True`) and proceeds only when a valid number is entered, we escape the loop using `break`